# How to install flash player 11.2 and Air 3.2 on FLash CS5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

So how I do that - couldn't find any info on adobe's site..
Thanks

Update:
Here is what I've done:

- downloaded playerglobal11_2.swc from Adobe
- created folder  Adobe/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Players/FP11.2, renamed the downloaded swc to playerglobal.swc and put it inside that folder
- inside Adobe/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Players duplicated FlashPlayer10_2.xml, called it FlashPlayer11_2.xml  and edited following lines

  ```
  <player id="FlashPlayer11.2" version="13" asversion="3">
  <name>Flash Player 11.2</name>
  <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.2/playerglobal.swc" />
  ```

Now when I start flash I can choose to publish to Flash Player 11.2 from drop down menu, when I publish it (ctrl+F12) in browser with this code on first keyframe:

```
import flash.display.Stage3D;

var stage3d = new Stage3D();   

var my_fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
my_fmt.color = 0xFF0000;
my_fmt.size = 32;
my_fmt.bold = true;
my_fmt.font  = "Arial";

var textF: TextField = new TextField;
textF.defaultTextFormat = my_fmt;
textF.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
textF.text = "Hello Flash Player: " + Capabilities.version + "\n" + stage3d;

addChild(textF);
```

I get this error in debugger:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2012: Stage3D$ class cannot be instantiated.
```

Obviously I missed something or done wrong, because I can't access FP11 API.

Comment: hey when you work it out i want to know iv been at this for a week also tried other 3d engines, Away3d-4.0 / Alternativa 8 and i cant either one started, i did all the above steps as what is written all over the net but no results.

Answer (score 2):

I've just ran into the same problem. I realize that the error #2012 is a runtime error, so it means compilation was ok and therefore your setup should be working. The problem lies in the player side of things. Here's how I solved it:

1. Make sure you update your flash players from here. If your web browsers already have the updated version, test in your web browser using Ctrl+F12. Otherwise, you need to update your flash debug player:
   http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
2. The code given is no longer valid. The Stage3D reference must be retrieved from the stage.

   ```
   var stage3d = stage.stage3Ds[0];
   ```
3. For debugging purposes, you can try this code instead, which will print the version and error message if there are problems.

   ```
   import flash.display.Stage3D;

   var my_fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
   my_fmt.color = 0xFF0000;
   my_fmt.size = 32;
   my_fmt.bold = true;
   my_fmt.font  = "Arial";

   var textF: TextField = new TextField;
   textF.defaultTextFormat = my_fmt;
   textF.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;  
   textF.width = this.stage.stageWidth;
   textF.wordWrap = true;
   textF.multiline = true;
   addChild(textF);


   try
   {
       var stage3d:Stage3D = stage.stage3Ds[0];
       textF.text = "Hello Flash Player: " + Capabilities.version + "\n" + stage3d;
   }
   catch(e:Error)
   {
       textF.text = "Hello Flash Player: " + Capabilities.version + "\n" + e.toString();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

- [Adding FP11 Support to Flash Pro CS5 and CS5.5](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html)

Once you install the .mxp located there, you'll be able to publish as FP11:

[image]

And finally be able to make use of impressive libraries like [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/).

Comment: Thnks I tried it but it didn't work, I have updated my question, maybe have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set version="15" (as opposed to version="13") in the FlashPlayer11_2.xml file.

```
<player id="FlashPlayer11.2" version="15" asversion="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/20583114199/air32-in-flash-cs-55

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll try that as soon as I get that FP11 running.
P.S - I have updated my question.